# Active Directory sysvol Check script using Powershell Jobs

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, sysvol

I am working on a sysvol check script for active directory monitoring. Completed the script which checks connectivity to sysvol on all the domain controllers in the given domain. As part of this i am doing the below check

```
Start-Job -sb "(Measure-Command{Dir \\$DCName\sysvol\$Domain\Policies}).Milliseconds"
```

this returns the time taken in milliseconds; unfortunately it returns the time even the sysvol is inaccessible and its even faster compared to if its accessible, due to obvious reasons.

My question is  when i do receive-Job , is there a way to find out if job has errors? because measure command doesn't give the whole picture. Please let me know if any other additional questions regarding this.

Comment: Seems like it would be far more straight forward if the share/path existed, then perform the throughput test.

Comment: Problem is i do entirely separate loop for receiving data for every completed job and write it to a file; if i skip a job because the path isn't there; i wont be receiving anything regarding that DC. Also my spreadsheet is a appending every-time i run the script by adding a new column labeled by current run time, so i don't have any control over cells to put data outside of jobs.  Please let me know if my explanation doesn't make any sense ,i can explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I don't understand your syntax. I'm running PS v5 on Windows 10 and your code snippet doesn't even run, because you fed `Start-Job` a string, not a script block. And `-sb` was not an acceptable alias/shorthand for `-ScriptBlock` for me.

But who knows, maybe that was legal in PS v4. That's beside the point.

You should add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `dir`/`gci`/`get-childitem` cmdlet so that it produces a "terminating" error if it fails.

Behold, here is the job when I do not specify `-ErrorAction Stop`:

```
PS C:\> $MyJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { (Measure-Command{Dir \\$DCName\sysvol\$Domain\Policies}).Milliseconds }
PS C:\> $MyJob.State
Running
PS C:\> $MyJob.State
Completed
```

I won't know whether the job actually succeeded or failed. The state of the job simply goes from Running to Completed, regardless of the job's success.

Now let's try it again with a terminating error:

```
PS C:\> $MyJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { (Measure-Command{Dir \\$DCName\sysvol\$Domain\Policies -ErrorAction Stop}).Milliseconds }
PS C:\> $MyJob.State
Running
PS C:\> $MyJob.State
Failed
```

Now you see that the same job enters a state of Failed. You now know your job failed. In addition, if you were to save the results of the job with

```
PS C:\> $Result = Receive-Job $MyJob
```

`$Result` will be null if the job failed.

If you want to store the specific error that occurred within the job, try this:

```
PS C:\> Receive-Job $MyJob -ErrorVariable Result
PS C:\> $Result
Cannot find path '\\\sysvol\\Policies' because it does not exist.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\\sysvol\\Policies:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Comment: Ryan you are right, i didnt want to confuse y'all so shortened my syntax; below is the full version;                                                                            $Block = "(measure-Command{Dir   \\$DCName\sysvol\$Domain\Policies}).Milliseconds"
        $sb = [scriptblock]::Create($Block)        
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -Name $DCName                              PS: Dang code notation is not at all working, tried to put 4 spaces at start still it shows normally.